# Keycloak Long lived token for Mobile Apps

Tags: jwt, keycloak, access-token, hybrid-mobile-app, keycloak-rest-api

we have a Mobile App & we use Keycloak as our authentication system. We receive both access_token & refresh_token via Keycloak Rest API.

Although I have X days set in "Access Token Lifespan" -> Keycloak Client Settings, my token expires in few minutes of inactive state & I am redirected to the login page.

I would like to know how to use Keycloak for Mobile Apps authentication & have longlived token.